# Change font-size for a single scope in Sublime Text 2

Tags: text-editor, font-size, sublimetext2

Is it possible in a `.tmTheme` file for Sublime Text 2 to change the font-size in a single scope?
I couldn't find any documentation on what keys I had available.

What I really want to do, is make the name of the section in `\section{name}` in LaTeX in a different size font, with something like:

```
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.name.section.latex</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>font_size</key>
    <string>20</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Just FYI, I got this answered for textmate 2 here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98574/textmate-2-how-can-increase-font-size-of-sections-in-the-markup-code and I would really like to see this work in Sublime Text 2!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be possible in Sublime Text 2 or 3. See this post for details [Per-token font size in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414173/per-token-font-size-in-sublime-text-2).

I have also tried to change font-family (e.g. consolas or helvetica) based on scope, which seems to be equally impossible. I'm not sure why this functionality isn't available, so maybe if you send Jon Skinner an email, he'll fix it for you ;)

Comment: Please don't make an answer pointing to another post/answer. Just mark the post as duplicate and move on.