# Per-token font size in Sublime Text 2

Tags: fonts, themes, sublimetext2, token, code-formatting

Apologies if this has already been answered but I couldn't find any duplicates.

Is it possible to set font sizes on a per-token basis in Sublime Text 2? For example, all 'function' tokens would be size 10 whereas 'functionName' would be size 30? I've put together a rough mock-up of what I want to achieve:

[image: Mockup of per-token font-sizes in Sublime Text 2]

The motivation here is to make it easier for you to focus on the important parts of your code - especially when skimming. I would suspect that such a thing should be possible given that, by default, ST2 already applies different fonts to different tokens (e.g. 'var' vs. 'c = a;' in switchVars()).

If it is not a feature, does ST2 provide the ability to implement this as a plugin? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pluma, from the Mate Desktop, is able to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, as there are no directives in the [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) or in color schemes for dealing with font size at that level of granularity.

However, it is possible to provide additional highlighting to your color scheme (`.tmTheme` file) so that function definitions stand out. It looks like you're using Monokai, so open `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme` and add the following to the end, just before the final `</array>`:

```xml
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Function definition</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>meta.function</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#000080</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

This will highlight your function definition lines in a dark blue:

[image: monokai highlight]

It also works for alternate function definition syntaxes:

[image: jquery1]
[image: jquery2]

Good luck!

Comment: As this question was about Sublime Text 2, has things changed at all in version 3?

Comment: @MarcusOttosson - `.tmTheme` files are the same in ST2 and ST3, so this answer is applicable to both versions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was referring to the original question, in having variable font-sizes on "tokens".

Comment: @MarcusOttosson - oh, ok. No, things haven't changed yet in ST3 - the `"font_size"` option in your preferences is global, so there isn't a way to change it on a per-line or per-word basis.

Comment: Since this just came up in the IRC channel: It still hasn't changed and doubtly ever will because the advantage gained from this rather large-scale scale change is minimal.