# Per-scope font size in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

This wasn't possible in ST2 (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414173/per-token-font-size-in-sublime-text-2) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018066/change-font-size-for-a-single-scope-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1)), but TextMate 2 does support this, and ST uses TM language bundles. Is there a way to do this in ST3?

Comment: This would be a handy feature.